# Hyperbolic Functions Proof

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I need help in proving this.

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(sinh^{-1}x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$

I'm supposed to use the Chain Rule.

I tried proving RHS and got stuck

Let $ y=sinh^{-1}x $ therefore $ x=sinh y $
$$ x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} $$

Then I tried LHS since chain rule looks applicable there

Let $ u=\sqrt{1+x^2} $
$$ du = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx $$
$$ (\frac{d}{du}\frac{1}{u})\frac{du}{dx} $$
$$ (-\frac{1}{u^2}) \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
$$ -\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

And I'm stuck.......can this even be solved?

Comment: $\sinh \big( \sinh^{-1} (x) \big )=x$. Start derivating that and remember that $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\sinh^{-1}x$$
$$\sinh y=\sinh \sinh^{-1}x=x$$
Differentiating both sides,
$$\cosh y\ dy=\ dx$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\cosh y}$$

We know that $\forall \ a \in \Bbb R$$$\cosh^2a=1+\sinh^2a $$

It thus follows that

$$\frac{1}{\cosh y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Comment: so chain rule wasn't necessary right?